# PHP Uploading Text File with a Variable Name

Tags: php, mysql

So right now I am trying to upload a .txt file and send it to mysql. That part works fine. But I have my code looking for a set file name, like text.txt. The txt file is being ftp'd into a directory, then a button in a php file is pressed and it looks for that file, reads it and sends it to the db. However, the file is going to  be ftp'd with different names everday, like date. It will be uploaded like this: test20130802.txt

How do I get my code to look for that date variable? It won't always be today's date either.

Here is part of my current code:

```
$handle = @fopen("test.txt", "r"); 

$values='';

while (!feof($handle)) 
{
$buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); 
//MYSQL QUERY......
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `$filename = $some_date_value . '.txt';` Are you looking for this?

Comment: I don't think so. I need the `$handle = @fopen("test.txt", "r");` line to look in the directory for testRANDOMDATE.txt instead of test.txt

Comment: YOu shold set name for `fopen`. It can be `test.txt` or `'test' . $my_random_date . '.txt'`. Or you want to scan directory and find a specific file?

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straightforward I think.

First you take the name of the file "test20130802.txt" into a variable. e.g.

```
$readTestFile = "test20130802.txt"; //Or however you are taking the file name as input
```

Hopefully, you are getting a standard file name. (By standard I mean that the first few letters are consistently the same always.)

In case of standard file name:

```
$dateYearChar = array();
$dateMonthChar = array();
$dateDateChar = array();

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
$dateYearChar[$i] = $readTestFile[$i+4];
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
$dateMonthChar[$i] = $readTestFile[$i+8];
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
$dateDateChar[$i] = $readTestFile[$i+10];

$dateYear = intval($dateYearChar);
$dateMonth = intval($dateMonthChar);
$dateDate = intval($dateDateChar);
```

Edit: And you can do the reverse thing if you want to look for a filename with the specified format.

e.g.

```
$fileName = "test" . $dateYear . $dateMonth . $dateDate . ".txt"
```